Calculate the probability that $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=16$ will intersect $x^2+y^2=25$, where $\lvert{a}\rvert\leq2$ and $\lvert{b}\rvert\leq3$.
I was working through an exam paper recently and I encountered the following question:

Calculate the probability that $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=16$ will intersect $x^2+y^2=25$, where $\lvert{a}\rvert\leq2$ and $\lvert{b}\rvert\leq3$, given that it is equally likely that $a$ ad $b$ will be at any point within the given ranges.

I reasoned as follows. It is clear that both curves are circles. The first one, say $C_1$, has centre $(a,b)$ and radius $4$ while the second one, say $C_2$, has centre $(0,0)$ and radius $5$. In order for $C_1$ not to intersect $C_2$, it is necessary that both $\lvert a \rvert$ and $\lvert b \rvert$ will be $\leq 1$. The probability that $\lvert a \rvert\leq 1$ seems to be $2/4=1/2$ (since the length of the allowed interval is $6$ and the length of the interval within that, such that if $a$ was inside it there would be no intersection, is $2$), and the probability that $\lvert b \rvert\leq 1$ seems to be $2/6=1/3$. If so, the probability that both and $\lvert a \rvert$ and $\lvert b \rvert$ will be $\leq 1$ is apparently $1/2\times 1/3=1/6$. If so, the probability that they will intersect should be $1-1/6=5/6$.
However, the answer they provide is $(24-\pi)/24$, which they obtained by working out the area of the sections which $C_1$ could and couldn't be in if it would intersect $C_2$.
What is wrong with my solution?
Thanks for your help.

Your bounds for $a$ and $b$ are not really correct. For example, your region has the point $(9/10,9/10)$ in it, but the circles are intersecting.

Here's an interactive graphic to help visualize the feasible region (the filled black rectangle with the circle in the center removed. You can drag the center point $(a, b)$ and drag it around.

I have added an answer which gives you explicit analytical expressions so that you can get the bounds for $(a,b)$ for intersection (or non-intersection).

@SammyBlack +1 (also) : Really great comment.

The problem is when you said

In order for $C_1$ not to intersect $C_2$, it is necessary that both $\lvert a \rvert$ and $\lvert b \rvert$ will be $\leq 1$.

That is in fact a necessary condition here, but is insufficient.  It would have been better if you had said

$C_1$ does not intersect $C_2$ precisely when $a^2+b^2 \lt (5-4)^2$ or when $a^2+b^2 \gt (5+4)^2$.

and that will give you the expected answer, since a circle radius $1$ has area $\pi$ and $a^2+b^2 \gt (5+4)^2$ is outside your rectangle.

For readers : The conditions Henry mentions come from the fact that two circles intersect precisely when the distance $d$ between their centres satisfy $|r_1-r_2|\le d\le (r_1+r_2)$, where $r_1,r_2$ are the radii of the circles.

Here are some explicit analytical details which might make it easier for you.
See that any point on the circle $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=16$ can be written as $(a+4\cos(\theta),b+4\sin(\theta))$ for $\theta\in(0,2\pi]$.
So, the above circle will intersect the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=25$ if and only if $(a+4\cos(\theta))^{2}+(b+4\sin(\theta))^{2}=25$ for some $\theta$.
i.e. (by expanding out the above expression) the region for $(a,b)$ such that there is intersection is given by
\begin{align}&\bigg\{(a,b):\exists \theta\in(0,2\pi]\,, a^{2}+8(a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta))+b^{2}=9\bigg\}\end{align}
But see that $$a^{2}+b^{2}-8\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\leq a^{2}+b^{2}+8(a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta))\leq a^{2}+b^{2}+8\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$
Let $r=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$
Then the see that $r^{2}+8r<9$ for all $r<1$ and so $a^{2}+8(a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta))+b^{2}<r^{2}+8r<9$ for all $\theta\in(0,2\pi]$ and we cannot have intersection.
And for $r>9$, we have $r^{2}-8r-9=(r-1)(r-9)>0$ and hence $r^{2}-8r>9$ and hence $a^{2}+b^{2}+8(a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta))>r^{2}-8r>9$ for all $\theta\in(0,2\pi]$ and we cannot have intersection.
Also see that if $1\leq r\leq 9$, then as $$a^{2}+b^{2}+8(a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta))=r^{2}+8r\sin(\theta+\arctan(\frac{a}{b}))$$
the equation $r^{2}+8r\sin(\theta+\arctan(\frac{a}{b}))=9$ or $\sin(\theta+\arctan(\frac{a}{b}))=\frac{9-r^{2}}{8r}$ will have atleast one solution for $\theta\in(0,2\pi]$ and this will give you one of the point(s) of intersection.
Thus the region for intersection is given by $\{r\geq 1\}\cap\{r\leq 9\}$
Now since  $(a,b)$ follows a uniform distribution on the rectangle $[-2,2]\times[-3,3]$, you always have $r<9$. So the only values of $(a,b)$ for which there is no interesection is when $r<1$ or $a^{2}+b^{2}<1$.
So the probability of no intersection is $$\frac{\pi}{\text{area of rectangle}}=\frac{\pi}{24}$$
